# Modular Arithmetic problem: Show that $\sum_{k=1}^{99}{(x+k)^2} = y^z$ is not solvable in integers x,y,z if z>1

Tags: modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

Expanding the LHS:

$\sum_{k=1}^{99}{(x+k)^2}
= 99x^2 + 2(\sum_{k=1}^{99}{k})x + (\sum_{k=1}^{99}{k^2}) = 99x^2 + 9900x + 33\times50\times199$

Reducing it to (mod 99) gives:

$66 \equiv y^z \space\space$ (mod 99)

or Reducing it to (mod 33) (or any other factors) gives:

$0 \equiv y^z \space\space$ (mod 33)

Then I don't know how to show that $y^z$ has no solutions for $z>1$.

Could anyone offer a hint or a solution?

Comment: http://math.hashcode.ru/questions/71079/диофантовы-уравнения-суммы-последовательных-квадратов?страница=1&focusedAnswerId=71097#71097

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$$y^z = 99x^2 + 9900x + 33 \times 50 \times 199 = 3(3(11)x^2 + 3(1100)x + 11(50)(199))$$

Since the first $2$ terms in the brackets have a factor of $3$ but the third one does not, this indicates $y^z$ has *exactly* $1$ factor of $3$. Because $3$ is prime, we get that $3 \mid y^z \; \to \; 3 \mid y$ (e.g., using [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma)), i.e., $y$ has at least $1$ factor of $3$. Thus, $y^z$ has at least $z$ factors of $3$. However, since $y^z$ actually has only one factor of $3$, this means $z$ can't be more than $1$.

Comment: Yes I know it has a factor or 3, or 11 if that's relevant but I'm afraid I still don't know how to solve it...

Comment: @Nibikibaba Note that with $11$, the expression may have more than one factor of it, but $3$ is different in that there is always *exactly* one factor of $3$. I added some more details to my answer explaining how to use this detail. Please let me know if anything is not clear now.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I understand now. The LHS after factoring out the 3 becomes 33x^2+3300x+11x50x199, which is 2 (mod 3) i.e. not divisible by 3. I have been trying to applying mod. arith. arguments to solve it but this solution does not feel like one to me. So I am still a bit confused about why this problem is placed under that topic...

Comment: @Nibikibaba If you want to phrase this in terms of modular arithmetic, then you might want to reduce modulo $9$.

Answer (score 0):

You have shown that $33|y^{z}$ and since $33 = 11 \cdot 3$ where both are prime,

if $z > 1$, then $33|y^{z} \implies 33|y \implies 99|y^{z}$ and checking $\pmod {99}$ on your above expression leaves

$y^{z} \equiv 0 \equiv 33 \cdot 50 
 \equiv 66\pmod{99}$ a contradiction.